# SQL querying/searching records from inner join's columns

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, where-clause, sql-like

**The query:**

```
   SELECT 
        (STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),mode.model_name)  
        FROM InventoryMake SUB INNER JOIN Model mode ON SUB.model_ID = mode.model_ID 
        WHERE SUB.inv_ID = CAT.inv_ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )) [Models],CAT.inv_ID 
    FROM Inventory CAT
```

**Results from the query are as below:**

```
Models                         inv_ID
Pulsar,Hunk                      14
Splender,Hunk                    15
Chaly (CF50),Hunk,CBZ,Splender   16
Pulsar,Hunk                      17
Pulsar,Hunk,CBZ                  18
```

As you can see from the query above InventoryMake table has the foreign keys from the tables Inventory and Model. Shown below are illustrations of those tables.

**Inventory table**

```
inv_ID    inv_name
14         abc
15         bcx
16         glx
17         lco
18         btx
```

**InventoryMake table**

```
inm_id  inv_ID  model_ID
1        2        15
7        3        15
8        5        16
9        3        16
10       4        16
11       2        16
12       1        14
13       3        14
14       1        17
15       3        17
```

**Model Table**

```
model_ID   model_name
1           Pulsar
2           Splender
3           Hunk
4           CBZ
5           Chaly (CF50)
```

What I need to do is to find the records for the users input that matches either inv_ID from the Inventory table or the model_name from the Model table. For that I have edited the query as below.

```
  SELECT 
        (STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),mode.model_name)  
        FROM InventoryMake SUB INNER JOIN Model mode ON SUB.model_ID = mode.model_ID 
        WHERE SUB.inv_ID = CAT.inv_ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )) [Models],CAT.inv_ID 
    FROM Inventory CAT WHERE CAT.inv_ID  LIKE '%@term%'
```

From the above query its possible to find the records that matches the term in inv_ID. But I need to find the records that matches either Inventory.inv_ID or Model.model_name. How do you suggest I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.
PS: I'm using MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

I don't knwo why your query has a function called STUFF neither what is FOR XML PATH('').

I'm also not sure about the meaning of '%@term%', or if it works as you seem to expect (it would not work in MySQL.

So, ignoring your query and looking at your formulated question, my answer is:

```
SELECT     SUB.inm_id, SUB.inv_ID, SUB.model_ID
FROM       InventoryMake SUB
INNER JOIN Inventory CAT ON (SUB.inv_ID = CAT.inv_ID)
INNER JOIN Model         ON (SUB.model_ID = Model.model_ID)
WHERE      CAT.inv_ID  = @term
   OR      Model.model_name LIKE '%@term%'
```

Note that it does not make much sense to use LIKE against CAT.inv_ID. Maybe what you want is actually to match user's input against inv_name?

Comment: STUFF and FOR XML PATH('') is similar to GROUP_CONCAT() in MYSQL. And no this is not what I expected. But thanks for trying to help me out here.

Comment: why is it that my answer does not reply to "What I need to do is to find the records for the users input that matches either inv_ID from the Inventory table or the model_name from the Model table."

Comment: Your query is right but you have altered my original query.